# a query about ~.setStop() method

Tags: sumo

I have a query about ~.setStop() method. I defined my flow as following for generating a scenario in which the relevant vehicles (type car1) enter the network, stop for 10 seconds at the determined position and finally, start moving again and leave the network.

```
<vType id = "car1" vClass = "passenger" guiShape = "passenger" color = "red" length = "5.5" maxSpeed = "30" />
<flow id = "f1" type="car1"  begin="5" end= "900" departSpeed = "10" departLane = "0" arrivalLane = "0" number = "5"  from = "e1" to = "e3" />"
```

Then I called the flow with this part of the code:

```
while step < 1000:
        traci.simulationStep()
        for veh_id in traci.vehicle.getIDList():
            length = traci.vehicle.getLength(veh_id)
            lane_id = traci.vehicle.getLaneIndex(veh_id)
            if length == 5.5 :
               traci.vehicle.setStop(veh_id, "e2",  laneIndex=0, flags = 0, duration = 10)
        step += 1
traci.close()
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I expect vehicles to stop for 10 seconds and then to continue their route but, they stop where is determined till the end of the simulation and make a queue. How can I fix this issue?
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are issuing setStop in each step again for the same vehicle thus the duration is always 10 seconds from now and it stops indefinitely.

Comment: I know what you said but I have no idea to fix it. I even tried some methods like ~getWaitingTime to put a constraint to break the loop but they didn't work. Could you let me know what solution you prefer?

Comment: You can just store the vehicle ids of the vehicles you have handled in a list and check whether the vehicle has already been handled